# Josephus permutation - follow up

Tags: performance, tree, rust

Follow up of [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122624/josephus-permutation)

Changes:

1. The `pop_min` function now panics if the tree is empty.
2. Moved the `size` attribute to the `Tree` struct.
3. Applied most of the suggestions given by the answers.
4. Added some other functions.
5. Refactored some functions.
6. Moved everything to the same file.

```
extern crate itertools;
use itertools::Unfold;
use std::cmp::Ordering;


pub fn permutation(size: u32, m: u32) -> Box<Iterator<Item = u32>> {
    let mut tree = Tree::new(1, size);
    let x = Unfold::new(1, move |a| {
        *a = (*a + m - 2) % tree.size + 1;
        Some(tree.pop_rank(*a))
    });
    Box::new(x.take(size as usize))
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    data: u32,
    left: Tree,
    right: Tree,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Tree {
    size: u32,
    root: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

impl Tree {
    fn new(from: u32, to: u32) -> Tree {
        if from > to {
            return Tree { root: None, size: 0, };
        }
        let mid = from + (to - from) / 2;
        let node = Node {
            data: mid,
            left: Tree::new(from, mid - 1),
            right: Tree::new(mid + 1, to),
        };

        Tree {
            size: 1 + node.left.size + node.right.size,
            root: Some(Box::new(node)),
        }
    }

    fn find_rank(&mut self, rank: u32) -> &mut Tree {
        let r = self.root
                    .as_mut()
                    .expect("rank out of range")
                    .left
                    .size + 1;

        self.size -= 1;
        match rank.cmp(&r) {
            Ordering::Equal => self,
            Ordering::Less => self.as_mut().left.find_rank(rank),
            Ordering::Greater => self.as_mut().right.find_rank(rank - r),
        }
    }

    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Box<Node> {
        self.root.as_mut().unwrap()
    }

    fn as_ref(&self) -> &Box<Node> {
        self.root.as_ref().unwrap()
    }

    fn empty(&self) -> bool {
        self.root.is_none()
    }

    fn delete_node(&mut self) {
        *self = self.root
                    .take()
                    .map(|mut x| {
                        if x.left.empty() {
                            x.right
                        } else if x.right.empty() {
                            x.left
                        } else {
                            x.data = x.right.pop_min();
                            Tree {
                                root: Some(x),
                                size: self.size,
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .expect("Can't delete None");
    }

    fn pop_min(&mut self) -> u32 {

        if self.empty() {
            panic!("underflow");
        }

        if self.as_ref().left.empty() {
            let data = self.as_ref().data;
            *self = self.root.take().unwrap().right;
            data
        } else {
            self.size -= 1;
            self.as_mut().left.pop_min()
        }
    }

    fn pop_rank(&mut self, rank: u32) -> u32 {
        let ranked = self.find_rank(rank);
        let data = ranked.as_ref().data;
        ranked.delete_node();
        data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mostly looks OK, but I really don't like

```
*self = self.root
            .take()
            .map(|mut x| {
                if x.left.empty() {
                    x.right
                } else if x.right.empty() {
                    x.left
                } else {
                    x.data = x.right.pop_min();
                    Tree {
                        root: Some(x),
                        size: self.size,
                    }
                }
            })
            .expect("Can't delete None");
```

You can shift up the `expect` to get

```
let mut node = self.root.take().expect("Can't delete None");
*self =
    if node.left.empty() {
        node.right
    } else if node.right.empty() {
        node.left
    } else {
        node.data = node.right.pop_min();
        Tree {
            root: Some(node),
            size: self.size,
        }
    };
```

which is already much nicer. Then deal with the error and naming:

```
fn delete_root_node(&mut self) {
    let mut root = self.root.take().expect("Empty tree has no root");
    *self =
        if root.left.empty() {
            root.right
        } else if root.right.empty() {
            root.left
        } else {
            root.data = root.right.pop_min();
            Tree {
                root: Some(root),
                size: self.size,
            }
        };
}
```

Then I'd flatten it back out

```
fn delete_root_node(&mut self) {
    let mut root = self.root.take().expect("Empty tree has no root");

    if root.left.empty() {
        *self = root.right
    } else if root.right.empty() {
        *self = root.left
    } else {
        root.data = root.right.pop_min();
        self.root = Some(root);
    };
}
```

Rust's tools are great, but they shouldn't be abused. In this case, a simple imperative style reads much nicer than the semi-functional transformations, so should be preferred.

More rightward drift can be dealt with in `find_rank`:

```
fn find_rank(&mut self, rank: u32) -> &mut Tree {
    let right_offset = self.as_mut().left.size + 1;

    self.size -= 1;
    match rank.cmp(&right_offset) {
        Ordering::Equal => self,
        Ordering::Less => self.as_mut().left.find_rank(rank),
        Ordering::Greater => self.as_mut().right.find_rank(rank - right_offset),
    }
}
```

Now, `find_rank` is doing something really horrible:

```
self.size -= 1;
```

This *breaks* the `Tree`'s invariants. Much better would be to call this `pop_rank` and move `pop_rank` inside of it. You can make this a bit nicer by having `pop_root` return a `u32` and just depending on that, though.

Then we have a nice chain of functions

```
fn pop_rank(&mut self, rank: u32) -> u32 {
    let left_size = self.as_mut().left.size;
    self.size -= 1;

    match rank.cmp(&(1 + left_size)) {
        Ordering::Equal   => {
            self.size += 1;
            self.pop_root()
        },
        Ordering::Less    => self.as_mut().left.pop_rank(rank),
        Ordering::Greater => self.as_mut().right.pop_rank(rank - 1 - left_size),
    }
}

fn pop_root(&mut self) -> u32 {
    let mut root = self.root.take().expect("Empty tree has no root");
    let data = root.data;

    if root.left.empty() {
        *self = root.right
    } else if root.right.empty() {
        *self = root.left
    } else {
        root.data = root.right.pop_min();
        self.root = Some(root);
        self.size -= 1;
    };

    data
}

fn pop_min(&mut self) -> u32 {
    if self.as_ref().left.empty() {
        let data = self.as_ref().data;
        *self = self.root.take().unwrap().right;
        data
    } else {
        self.size -= 1;
        self.as_mut().left.pop_min()
    }
}
```

The restoring of `self.size` in `pop_rank` before calling `pop_root` might slightly increase computational burden but it means that each function only relies on the data structure's basic invariants to work properly.

Note that `pop_min` doesn't actually need to `panic!` as that's captured by `self.as_ref`'s auto-panic.

`as_ref` and `as_mut` are misleading names since they actually give handles to `root`; better would be `get_root` and `get_root_mut`. I'd also swap `pop_min` for `pop_first` for clarity.

I'd also change `m` to `step` in `permutation`.

---

I've been transfixed by this problem for a while now, so I'm going to introduce my thoughts about it. **Very little of what follows has anything to do with your implementation, but hopefully someone at least finds it a little interesting.**

It's worth noting that `Box`-heavy structures tend to be slow. A much more efficient tree structure to work with could be a `Vec<Vec<usize>>` like so:

```
tree[0]               13
tree[1]        8               5
tree[2]    4       4       4       1
tree[3]  2   2   2   2   2   2   1
tree[4] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

`tree[0..3]` are used to guide you to an index in the bottom. "Using" the fifth value would result in the tree modified like so

```
tree[0]               12
tree[1]        7               5
tree[2]    4       3       4       1
tree[3]  2   2   1   2   2   2   1
tree[4] 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Then it's worth noting that you never actually need to read the right branches on traversal, so those can be discarded:

```
tree[0]               13
tree[1]        8               .
tree[2]    4       .       4       .
tree[3]  2   .   2   .   2   .   1
tree[4] 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1
```

Then move the size into the data structure itself, since that needs to be read frequently in the algorithm and not actually during traversal.

```
tree[0]        8               .
tree[1]    4       .       4       .
tree[2]  2   .   2   .   2   .   1
tree[3] 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1
```

I've found that just this gives a noticeable but underwhelming speed-up factor of 3-4x; I was expecting with all the `Box`ing for that to be closer to 10. The problem seems to be that the branches are still unpredictable and the behaviour is still cache-thrashing; the main improvement came not from the change in format but from not writing to the right branch (not the eliding step but just not writing to it). Plus, allocators are likely to put all those boxed values next to each other, and the lack of space efficiency doesn't really hurt when doing psuedo-random access anyway.

Then note that with something like a (14345577, 15347)-permutation, \$\log 14345577\$ is much greater than \$\log 15347\$. You can use this to your advantage by ignoring the top of the tree:

```
tree[ 0]             8388608 ...
tree[ 1]           4194304 ...
...
tree[ 8]       32768 ...
tree[ 9]     16384 ...
...
tree[22]   2 ...
tree[23] 1 ...
```

You can actually discard `tree[0..8]`; jumps are normally going to be no greater than steps of 15347 times the "sparsity" of the data. When the sparsity gets so large that you *are* taking jumps that large, you can "recompact" the whole array in \$O(n)\$ time. Since you only need to do this when density drops somewhere below 50%, this is a relatively cheap way of moving from a total \$O(n \log n)\$ to \$O(n \log m)\$ time complexity (resizing each time capacity halves results in only \$O(n)\$ extra work).

Note that the top level then becomes a bunch of roots into *sub-trees*, not a single tree. Thus you can't ignore the right-nodes, or you'll be losing the size of the tree. Conceptually, those right nodes are calculated from the node above, so if there's no node above you aren't able to drop the value.

An extreme example would be a (10000000, 3)-permutation, where the entire tree is clearly overkill. This tree trimming works well there.

Then it's worth looking at those bottom rows, to see if we can do something more intelligent about them:

```
tree[X]                            64   ...
...
tree[X]    4       4       4       4    ...
tree[X]  2   .   2   .   2   .   2   .  ...
tree[X] 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . 1 . ...
```

Despite the elided right branches, this is still a ton of data to express 64 bits of data. In fact, it uses *63 times* that amount of data even after elision. Much more effective is to have an actual 64 bit integer.

```
0b1111111111111111111111111...
```

This can still be efficiently binary searched by utilizing a specialized routine, bit shifts, masks and `u64::count_ones`. In fact, on newer x86 processors you don't even have to; [Jukka Suomela points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27453505/1763356) that it's as simple as

```
pub fn position_nth_set_bit(value: u64, mut bit: u32) -> u32 {
    // Holy smokes
    bmi_pdep_64(1 << bit, value).trailing_zeros()
}
```

Sadly I think right now I need to use `asm!`, but that's no show-stopper. If `pdep` isn't available, the binary search with `count_ones` is still pretty fast - but it's certainly not nearly *as* fast.

In fact, this also makes the compacting step that we need to elide the top of the tree much simpler; the bit-set acts as a mask over our values that we can just iterate.

---

Let's quickly calculate what the overhead is. Our entire tree looks like

```
roots           x              x
tree[X]     x       .       x
tree[X]   x   .   x   .   x   .
tree[X]  x . x . x . x . x . x .
masks    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
values   VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV  ← We don't need this until after compacting
```

`values` costs a `usize` per output value, but can actually be ignored until the first compaction as before then it's an identity map (`values[k] == k` at first).

`masks` introduces one further bit per value.

If you look at `tree` and `roots` the right way, you can see you can "slide" the `x`s down the right branches to fill exactly one row (I'll re-use this property later). The bottom-most `tree[X]` is at the 128 level (since `masks.count_ones()` works at the 64 level), so that's a usize of bits spent per 128 values.

Ergo we have 1-2 extra bits per value, and only half of the values actually need to be stored. So our space complexity is pretty close to `n * usize::BITS / 2`. If `m` is expected to approach `n` in size or space matters more than the move from \$O(n \log n)\$ to \$O(n \log m)\$, you can instead use `masks` without trimming the top of the tree, so no `values` array is needed, to get a space cost of roughly just `2 * n` bits.

A pleasing hybrid might be obtained by making `tree` a little bit taller, so one has to resize slightly less frequently. Two extra layers means two extra branches per iteration but delays resizing until the density is about 1/8, leaving memory consumption of about `n * usize::BITS / 8` while still having \$O(n \log m)\$ operations. Plus, doing the first resize early hurts as before it `values` is not used and the later resizes are smaller. On the other hand, a few extra branches is *expensive* when the branches are unpredictable, so it actually makes sense to keep the tree shallow and do a linear search over the roots. It's worth noting that resizing can make the tree smaller and isn't actually expensive, so the trade to do it later isn't so clear-cut. The precise parameters are tunable.

This is starting to feel optimal, since \$\log m\$ is about the smallest cost for a jump one can normally reasonably expect and we're approaching a small number of bits of overhead. However, we might be able to make the data structure more optimal. One possible improvement is to take the "compact" view of the tree we used to calculate its size: slide each value down the "right-hand slide":

```
roots           a              b
tree[X]     c       ↘       d
tree[X]   e   ↘   f   ↘   g   ↘
tree[X]  x ↘ x ↘ x ↘ x ↘ x ↘ x ↘
masks    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
values   VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
```

to get

```
tree     x e x c x f x a x g x d · · · b
masks    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
values   VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
```

Note that traversal is now just a binary search over a sub-range of the array. This might look tough to traverse, but it's actually a fairly mechanical transformation.

Generating this is more tough, but it does have the lovely property that each modulo is

```
1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, ...
```

which you can take the \$\log_2\$ of to get

```
0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, ...
```

[OEIS helpfully adds that](https://oeis.org/A007814),

> a(n) is the number of 0's at the end of n when n is written in base 2

and then you note that `n >> (n.trailing_zeros() + 1)` gives how many times you've seen this value before, which lets you deal with the leftover parts.

Note that the modulo is for a "cropped" root, and so you need to take the `min` against the top-level modulo you're using, and you also need to add 7 before then to multiply all the modulos by 128 (because the bottom groups of 64 are dealt with in `masks`).

---

With my implementation, for very large \$m\$ (same order of magnitude as \$n\$), the tree pruning is entirely ineffective (and is just pointless overhead), so the only performance gains come from the change in how iteration happens, the move to iteration over a contiguous vector and the `masks` array removing the last few layers of the tree. The move to a contiguous vector is actually rather ineffective as a speed enhancer since the `Box`es are probably contiguous anyway and the major overhead is in the unpredictable branching. There's roughly a factor 6 improvement over your code here.

For "medium"-sized \$m\$ (eg. \$n\$ is 14345577, \$m\$ is 15347), tree pruning comes into play and speed improves 3-fold. Your code does not, so the speed advantage increases. There's roughly a factor 20 improvement over your code here.

For small \$m\$ (eg. 3), the tree pruning pushes further increases speed significantly, resulting in massive decreases in time. Further, the BMI instructions at the bottom of the tree end up improving speed significantly. However, your code also becomes very predictable, since branches repeat frequently, so the cost there actually falls too and the overall *relative* speed improvement is not as great as the time reduction alone would imply. There's roughly a factor 32 improvement over your code here.

---

Honestly I was hoping for more, but I can see why the improvements were only this good. It should be possible to improve this a lot by using a B-tree instead of a binary tree, by effectively replacing

```
roots           x              x
tree[X]     x       .       x
tree[X]   x   .   x   .   x   .
tree[X]  x . x . x . x . x . x .
masks    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
values   VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
```

with

```
roots       x       x       x       x
tree[X]       .       .       .
tree[X]  x x x . x x x . x x x .
masks    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
values   VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
```

which should improve branch predictability by using intermittent unrolled linear searches. However, the reduction from doing this the "obvious" way is slight as you still end up with poorly predictable branches over spread-out locations.

Ideally, one should reorganize the values as

```
roots                      x x x x
tree[X]  x x x|x x x|x x x|
masks    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
values   VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
```

instead.

Another oversight I've been purposefully ignoring is SIMD. Small SIMD vectors for `usize`-sized data makes this relatively weak, but lower down the tree a `u16x8` vector is likely extremely useful, and basically makes an 8-wide B-tree optimal. Newer AVX instructions would do far better, and allow the whole tree to be heavily vectorized. I'm going to continue to ignore this, though, 'cause SIMD with Rust is not ideal right now.

Comment: I think I could read every one of your answers over and over; I love the level of detail and thoughtfulness you put in each one!